# Symfony DOMCrawler break from each

Tags: php, symfony, domcrawler

I'm trying to filter my html with DOMCrawler, but I need to break if result is found.

Is it possible to break from `each`?
Or how can I get `$node->text();` if I use `foreach`? Or it's not possible?

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="Center" rules="all" border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Entity Name</td>
        <td>NV Business ID</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>Type</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="">GOOGLE</a></td>
        <td><a href=""></a></td>
        <td><a href="">Expired</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Reserved Name</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="">GOOGLE INC.</a></td>
        <td><a href="">NV20161275322</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Active</a></td>
        <td><a href="">Foreign Corporation</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

PHP:

```
$client = new Client();
$client->setHeader('User-Agent', "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.15");
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://nvsos.gov/sosentitysearch/');
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Search')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form, array(
    'ctl00$MainContent$txtSearchBox' => 'google',
));
if($this->available == false)return;
$crawler->filter('table tr')->each(function (\Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler $element) {
    $status = $element->filter('td')->eq(2)->text();
    echo $status;
    if ($status == 'Active') {
        $this->available = false;
        break;
    }
});
```

I want to get status. And then if status is equal "Active", I want to break loop.

---

Ok, now I came up with something.

```
$crawler = $crawler->filter('#ctl00_MainContent_objSearchGrid_dgCorpSearchResults');
foreach ($crawler as $i => $content) {
    $crawler = new Crawler($content);
    foreach ($crawler->filter('#ctl00_MainContent_objSearchGrid_dgCorpSearchResults') as $node) {
        $longStatus = $node->nodeValue;
        echo $longStatus;
    }
}
```

But now I don't know how to get just third `<td>` in `<tr>`.

Comment: looks like it's not possible.

Comment: Can you give an example document and describe the result you like to get?

Comment: @xabbuh hey, updated my question.

Comment: Did you try to return instead of break ?

Comment: Yes, it was first what I tried. It's just printing all results instead of just breaking it.

Comment: Hmm I have it in foreach, but now I don't know how to get just third <td> in <tr>

Answer (score 4):

While you can not break from `$crawler->each()`, and of course you can not use `break` to exit a function, and there is nothing you can return so that `$crawler->each()` will stop iterating, but you still have a couple of options.

1. **Exceptions**!
   It's always an option to exit from most of functions.
2. **`foreach`**
   As you got it yourself, you can switch from `$crawler->each()` to `foreach`.
   But it's simpler than you think. Just replace

   ```
   $crawler->each(function($element) {
      your_code();
   });
   ```

   with

   ```
   foreach($crawler as $content) {
       $element = new Crawler($content);
       your_code();
   }
   ```

   No need to change anything in your code. And your original code becomes

   ```
   ...
   foreach($crawler->filter('table tr') as $content) {
       $element = new Crawler($content);
       $status = $element->filter('td')->eq(2)->text();
       echo $status;
       if ($status == 'Active') {
           $this->available = false;
           break;
       }
    }
   ```

   And you still can get third `<td>` in `<tr>` the same way

Comment: I had to use your foreach method to call `$client->click(...)` inside the loop. With the `$crawler->each()` my PHP script failed when I tried a new request inside the loop. Thank you!